# NHS Surcharge for UK Fiancé

Tags: visa, uk-citizens, marriage, nhs

I am asking about a policy query concerning the new NHS surcharge fee.  A British national wishes to bring his partner over to the UK on a fiancé visa.

I understand that anyone wishing to apply for a visa to work, study or join their family in the UK for a period of more than 6 months is eligible to pay this fee. Could you please tell me the position as regards a fiancé visa which will be granted for a period of 6 months only?

Comment: Were you living together outside of the UK, but inside of the EU/EEA for a while?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [goverment's site](https://www.gov.uk/healthcare-immigration-application/when-you-need-to-pay) you don't need to pay (or even get an IHS reference number) in any of the following cases:

- you are applying for a visitor visa from outside of the UK. This includes the [Marriage Visitor Visa](https://www.gov.uk/marriage-visa)
- you are applying for a visa from outside of the UK that only lasts at most 6 months (6 is still okay)
- you are a family member of an EEA citizen (This only applies to you if you've been living together outside of the UK, but inside the EU/EEA, see also [When returning to the UK from working in the EU, what do you need to show you activated your "Treaty Rights" WRT non-EU family members?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/611/when-returning-to-the-uk-from-working-in-the-eu-what-do-you-need-to-show-you-ac))

Based on this I think you don't need to pay the surcharge for this particular visa.